# Call only async-signal-safe functions in signal handlers?

Tags: linux, process, signals

I'm new to signal and signal handler and I was reading a book which says

> Call only async-signal-safe functions in your handlers. A function that is async-signal-safe, or simply safe, has the property that it can be safely called from a signal handler,because  because it cannot be interrupted by a signal handler. Notice that many popular functions, such as printf, sprintf, malloc, and exit, are no safe.

I'm a little bit confused here, below is my question:

what does it mean by safe functions cannot be interrupted by a signal handler?
Does it mean that safe functions internally blocks signals in the beginning and unblock signals before it finishes so that safe functions won't be interrupted by other signals?

Comment: Multiply posted at https://stackoverflow.com/q/63866949/340790 by a prolific multi-poster account.

Answer (score 3):

When the kernel delivers a signal to a process, it stops the execution of the process wherever it may be, injects a call to the signal handler function, then schedules the process, which causes it to execute the signal handler.  Because that call can be injected anywhere, your program could be in the middle of manipulating non-local state when the signal handler was injected.  Calling another function that depends on that non-local state would result in undefined behavior.

Any function that accesses/modifies non-local state is generally not signal safe.  From `man 7 signal-safety`:

> ```
> To avoid problems with unsafe functions, there are two possible
> choices:
>
> 1. Ensure that (a) the signal handler calls only async-signal-safe
>    functions, and (b) the signal handler itself is reentrant with
>    respect to global variables in the main program.
>
> 2. Block signal delivery in the main program when calling functions
>    that are unsafe or operating on global data that is also accessed by
>    the signal handler.
>
> Generally, the second choice is difficult in programs of any complexity,
> so the first choice is taken.
> ```

That man page goes on to enumerate the set of signal-safe functions.